# SQL wont Complete INSERT INTO (incorrect Date)

Tags: sql

Im attempting to insert data into a table using the INSERT INTO shown below:

```
INSERT INTO `paitent`(`PaitentID`, `fName`, `sName`, `DOB`, `Sex`, `NextOfKinFName`, `NextOfKinSName`, `NextOfKinRelationship`, `NextOfKinTelNo`, `DateOfAdmission`, `AdmissionNotes`, `PrescribedMedication`, `Doseage`, `StartMedDate`, `EndMedDate`, `MedFrequency`) VALUES (0001, "Peter", "Gregory", 1997-01-01, "Male", "Mary", "Gregory", "Wife", 09875463762, 2020-01-02, "Broken Leg", "N/A", "N/A", 2019-02-02, 2019-03-03, "N/A")
```

but when I run the SQL i get this error:

```
#1292 - Incorrect date value: '1995' for column 'DOB' at row 1
```

I cant understand why as there isn't even a 1995 date in the data that's being inputted.
Does anyone understand why I'm getting this error?

Comment: 1997-01-01 = 1995. Simple math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Date constants need to be enclosed in single quotes, so `'2020-01-02'`.  However, in Standard SQL (your question doesn't have a tag), it is even better to identify it as a date constant by using the prefix `date`:  `date '2020-01-02'` is the standard syntax for a date literal.